# Multiprocessing in python - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to access an API which to return a set of products. Since the execution is slow I was hoping could use multiprocessing to make it faster. The API works perfectly when accessed using a simple for loop.

Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import json

def f(a):
    request = Request('API'+ str(a)) 
    try:
        response = urlopen(request)
        data = response.read()
    except URLError, e:
        print 'URL ERROR:', e
    s=json.loads(data)
    #count += len(s['Results'])
    #print count
    products=[]
    for i in range(len(s['Results'])):
        if (s['Results'][i]['IsSyndicated']==False):        
            try:
                products.append(int(s['Results'][i]['ProductId']))
            except ValueError as e:
                products.append(s['Results'][i]['ProductId'])
    return products

list=[0,100,200]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)
    result=p.map(f, list)
    print result
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\z080302\Desktop\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/z080302/Desktop/Python_Projects/mp_test.py", line 36, in <module>
    result=p.map(f, list)
  File "C:\Users\z080302\Desktop\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\z080302\Desktop\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I was thinking even with multiprocessing the function will still be executed sequentially. So why am I getting `UnboundLocalError`?

Comment: If an error is thrown in the try block, data will never be assigned.

Comment: Most likely because the `urlopen(request)` command is throwing an exception, so `data` is never bound.

Comment: Check your indentation. Also, when pasting python code - it matters a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
try:
    response = urlopen(request)
    data = response.read()
except URLError, e:
    print 'URL ERROR:', e
```

If `urlopen` throws a `URLError` exception, the following line (`data = response.read()` is never executed.  So when you come to:

```
s=json.loads(data)
```

The variable `data` has never been assigned.  You probably want to abort processing in the event of a `URLError`, since that suggests you will not have any JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is about the actual problem, but I thought I'll add my experience for others who come here because of mystic errors raised by `multiprocessing`s `ApplyResult.get` with `raise self._value`. If you are getting `TypeError`, `ValueError` or basically any other error which in your case has nothing to do with `multiprocessing` then it's because that error is raised not by multiprocessing really, but by your code that you are running in the process that you are attempting to manage (or the thread if you happen to be using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` which I was).